# Error while installing geany

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-10.04, c++

I have recently downloaded geany 0.19.1.

---

[Installation Guide.](http://www.geany.org/manual/index.html#installation)

**Autotools based build system**

The Autotools based build system is very mature and has been well tested. To use it, you just need the Make tool, preferably GNU Make.

Then run the following commands:

> $ ./configure 
>   $ make

Then as root:

> % make install

---

I tried running **./configure** in my terminal and it ran successfully.

But when I try running **make** it gives me the this error.

```
searock@searock-desktop:~/Downloads/geany-0.19.1$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Can someone point me in a right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geany developers' PPA](https://launchpad.net/~geany-dev/+archive/ppa)

Comment: What is ppa:user/ppa-name ? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Something to do with apt. Like the page I linked to says, use **ppa:geany-dev/ppa**.